# JDK Version Not in Allowed Range

Tags: java, maven, mule

I'm using *Mule CE 3.7*, who uses *Maven* to compile it's project.
The problem is, when is compiling, he returns this error:

*[ERROR] Detected JDK Version: 1.8.0-60 is not in the allowed range [1.7,1.8].*

I already did all the solutions that i found, JAVA_HOME and PATH are configured.

If i run Java commands, they return me this:

```
MBP-de-axz:~ axz$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

MBP-de-axz:~ axz$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_60

MBP-de-axz:~ axz$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T08:57:37-03:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: pt_BR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

I already configured the Pom file of my project like this:

```
<requireJavaVersion>
     <version>[1.7,1.9)</version>
</requireJavaVersion>
```

So all is pointing to the same Java version.
And this is happening in my Mac and Windows. 
The project only works if i change to Java 1.7, but i can use 1.7 because one of my libraries uses Java 1.8.

Anyone have an ideia of what could it be ?

Thanks !

Comment: What mule version are you using? Only 3.7 and up support Java 8.

Comment: 3.7 CE, the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Mule is not compatible yet with JDK 1.8, i need to use JDK 1.7

I should have read the requeriments.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use `[1.7,1.9)` as version range. This means it accept version between `1.7` (inclusive) until `1.9` (exclusive). Since `1.8.0_60` is bigger than `1.8`, it was out of range with the previous version range. Btw, `[1.8)` would both include and exclude `1.8`, so that shouldn't work.

Comment: I did what you told, but same thing. The strange is that the error is the same (range 1.7, 1.8), but i put in Pow file 1.7,1.9. Maven uses the file from the project right ?

Comment: Did you include both the bracket and parenthese? What is the message?

Comment: Yes, i edited the post. The strange is the error is the same *is not in the allowed range [1.7,1.8]*. Looks like the Mule is not using the Pom file.

Comment: Try `mvn help:effective-pom` to discover how Maven resolves the pom. That should show you where the message is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

This error happens, when the maven JDK version and PROJECT JDK version doesn't match.

Inorder to fix that, try to find out the mvn jdk version first using

```
"mvn --version"
```

Then set the desired JDK version using `set JAVA_HOME="c:\jdk_location_here"`.  If you re-run the `"mvn --version"`. You will see the updated JDK Version there.Now try to run your build.

Long term: Set the JAVA_HOME in environment variables.